# SQL instead of multiple loops

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Is there a way to write SQL-code instead of looping through the data for

finding the difference between eDate in an Post compared to the following post's sDate. If the hours between them occur during night time (22:00-06:00) the Time that occur during night hours should be printed.

I have done this at the moment by looping the data in the table but with more functionality there are more and more loops in my current code.

```
ID  UserID      sDate           eDate
1   1       2017-01-01 01:00    2017-01-01 02:00    
2   1       2017-01-01 03:00    2017-01-01 06:00
```

for exampel:

```
nightStart = "2016-12-31 22:00";
nightEnd = "2016-01-01 06:00";
```

ID=1

```
eDate = "2017-01-01 02:00";
```

ID=2

```
sDate = "2017-01-01 03:00";
```

Should find the diffrence between eDate and sDate to be:

```
01:00
```

---

### UPDATE

Using the SQL-code example provided, then looping the results against the calcNightHoursInRange Method

SQL:

```
SELECT  
    THIS.RegTimeID,THIS.UserID,peDate=MAX(PREV.eDate),tseDate=THIS.sDate,diff=DATEDIFF(HOUR,MAX(PREV.eDate),THIS.sDate)
FROM
    tblRegTime THIS
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT  RegTimeID,UserID,eDate
        FROM
        tblRegTime
    )PREV ON THIS.UserID=PREV.UserID AND THIS.sDate>PREV.eDate
GROUP BY
    THIS.RegTimeID,THIS.UserID,THIS.sDate,THIS.eDate
```

-
Method:

```
    public TimeSpan calcNightHoursInRange(DateTime sDate, DateTime eDate, DateTime RuleStartTime, DateTime RuleEndTime)
    {
        //Build RuleStartDateTime & RuleEndDateTime
        DateTime baseDate = DateTime.Parse(sDate.ToShortDateString());
        DateTime RuleStartDateTime = new DateTime(baseDate.Year, baseDate.Month, baseDate.Day, RuleStartTime.Hour, RuleStartTime.Minute, 0);
        DateTime RuleEndDateTime = new DateTime(baseDate.Year, baseDate.Month, baseDate.Day, RuleEndTime.Hour, RuleEndTime.Minute, 0);

        if (RuleStartDateTime > RuleEndDateTime)
        {
            RuleEndDateTime = RuleEndDateTime.AddDays(1);
        }

        TimeSpan MatchTime = new TimeSpan();
        if (sDate <= RuleStartDateTime && eDate <= RuleEndDateTime)
        {
            MatchTime = (eDate - RuleStartDateTime);
        }
        if (sDate >= RuleStartDateTime && eDate <= RuleEndDateTime)
        {
            MatchTime = (eDate - sDate);
        }
        if (sDate <= RuleStartDateTime && eDate >= RuleEndDateTime)
        {
            MatchTime = (RuleEndDateTime - RuleStartDateTime);
        }
        if (sDate > RuleStartDateTime && eDate > RuleEndDateTime)
        {
            MatchTime = (RuleEndDateTime - sDate);
        }
        return MatchTime;
    }
```

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: What's your RDBMS?

Comment: @AaronDietz mssql

Comment: @JonasJohansson with such questions it is ALWAYS best to show the code you used so far as it else could look like you try to get ppl to do your work (and didn't do anything at all). I know that outlook can look unfair, but there were some cases there already, thus many see it as requirement that code is shown in questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you the LAG offset without using LAG, however, using LAG makes it easier.

```
SELECT  
    THIS.ID,THIS.UserID,THIS.sDate,THIS.eDate,diff=DATEDIFF(HOUR,THIS.sDate,MAX(PREV.eDate))
FROM
    YourTable THIS
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT  ID,UserID,eDate
        FROM
        YourTable
    )PREV ON THIS.UserID=PREV.UserID AND THIS.sDate>PREV.eDate
GROUP BY
    THIS.ID,THIS.UserID,THIS.sDate,THIS.eDate
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for `DATEDIFF()`:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(hh, '2017-01-01 02:00', '2017-01-01 03:00')
```

This will simply return `1`, the integer difference in hours.  You will have to format it to `01:00` if that is needed.

You can use `LEAD()` or `LAG()` to access the next row or previous row.  Something like this should be what you want:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(hh, edate, LEAD(sdate) over (ORDER BY ID))
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: I THINK  it is more complex a bit. He "only" wants to show the dates that are during the nighttime (thus the startdates and also the enddates taht are during the nighttime, while all other dates are not shown).

Comment: if i compare the same row this is very simple yes, but when comparing one row with the next row in order, how will i write the sql code for this

Comment: @JonasJohansson Not sure how much you need.  See the addition to my answer.  You may want a partition by userid, which would be `LEAD(sdate) over (PARTITION BY userID ORDER BY ID)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, sDate 
(
    SELECT eDate FROM TABLENAME t2 WHERE t2.ID = (t1.ID + 1))
) DIFFHOURS
FROM TABLENAME t1
```